# Global php file

Tags: php, html

Every php page starts with this:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name); 

session_start();
?>
```

So how can I make a .php file that save those variables and include them in the start of every html page. And if I want to use $con variable from it. how to use it.

Comment: Exactly like you say. Put the variables in another file and [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) that file.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me what a php developer always use to make a global file and save to use it all the time, other than the connections commands ? @GolezTrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better use `require_once` or `include_once`, because if you include one page to another with `include 'config.php';` on top - you get a message

`'A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()'`

PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php

Comment: yes exactly thats what happened after using include. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Put this code in a file (eg. config.php) and include/require it in all other php files

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

// here you could use the $con variable
```

PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: how can i acces the $con variable per example ?

Comment: @droidnation You simply use `$con`. If you require or include a file, you have to imagine that you simply attach it to the current .php file. Like copy/paste.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me what a php developer always use to make a global file and save to use it all the time, other than the connections commands ? @YUNOWORK

Comment: @droidnation Well, everyone needs different stuff ... you have to adjust the file to your project. I usually have important variables like my document root. Also, i use the global file to include and set up my libraries like my template engine. But as i said, you have to adjust the file all the time depending on the project.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. In a fewer months and more experience, I will make several global files to use. That comes with experience I guess. Thank you.